# Async socket connection, server GUI hangs(not responding) when client disconnect?

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm coding server and client based on [this](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/sockets/article.php/c8781/Asynchronous-Socket-Programming-in-C-Part-II.htm) guide. My server continuously send some data to clients.

Everything works great except server GUI hangs (not responding) for few second when one of clients disconnect due to *unexpected* problem (usually LAN cable disconnect or power outage). Then socket exception is throwing after few seconds hanging. It's not comfortable with someone sitting on Server computer. 
It doesn't cause any hanging problem if client disconnect properly, not because of power outage.
What is the cause? How to get rid of that hanging?

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate thread for the sockets, connections etc.
UI thread should be kept separate when task may take time.

If are uncomfortable with threads then you can use `Application.DoEvents()` method in your code. Although I don't recommend using this.

Comment: Can you give me link for working multi-threaded c# sample? I used codeguru sample because it included full working (both server and client) source code.

Comment: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14346/A-Simple-Multi-Threaded-Server-Client-Instant-Mess) you can try this one. The codeguru help you are taking also uses multithreading so GUI should not hang... you must know that sockets wait for the reply for the period of timeout. Be sure that the is GUI hanging or the socket connection is waiting for timeout.

Comment: How to timeout socket connection after 1 second? How to set that property? My case it hangs for few seconds.